# How to implement a many-to-many in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

There a many-to-many:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees_and_positions
    has_many :employees_positions, through: :employees_and_positions
end

class EmployeesAndPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employee
    belongs_to :employees_position
end

class EmployeesPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees_and_positions
    has_many :employees, through: :employees_and_positions
end
```

How to implement a choice (check_boxes) positions in the form when adding an employee?
I wrote this variant:

```
f.inputs 'Communications' do
    f.input :employees_positions, as: :check_boxes
end
```

It displays a list of positions in the form, but does not save nothing to the table (employees_and_positions).
How to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose you have an `employee`, you can reference the ids of the `employees_positions` association by using `employee.employees_position_ids`. Accordingly, you can mass assign pre-existing `EmployeesPosition` objects using a check_box for each `EmployeesPosition`, but you need to use the `employee_position_ids` attribute"

```
= f.input :employee_position_ids, as: :check_boxes, collection: EmployeesPosition.all
```

Also, make sure you've whitelisted the `employee_position_ids` param in your active admin resource:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Employee do
  permit_params employee_position_ids: []
end
```

http://activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html